# Distribution supported on a cross

Tags: distribution-theory

It is well known that a distribution supported on $\{0\}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a finite linear combination of derivatives of the unit measure $\delta_0$. Moreover, if $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is of finite order $k$ with $\text{supp}(u) \subset \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$, then it is of the form
\begin{align*}
u = \sum_{j \leq k} u_j \otimes \partial^j \delta_0,
\end{align*}
where $u_j \in  \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ are distributions of finite order $k-j$.
But what if instead the support of $u$ is a cross? That is, for example, $\text{supp}(u) = ([-1, 1] \times \{0\}) \cup (\{0\} \times [-1, 1])$.

It is not clear to me if there is (or should be) a similar decomposition. If $u$ is supported on a cross, then $0$ can be cut out, leaving a sum of two distributions that can be represented as above, plus a remainder supported in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $0$. But it does not seem possible to just get rid of this term by passing to a limit. I guess I am asking if in this case
\begin{align*}
u = \sum_{j \leq k} u_j^{(1)} \otimes \partial^j \delta_0 + \sum_{j \leq k} \partial^j \delta_0 \otimes u^{(2)}_j,
\end{align*}
where $u_j^{(1)}$ and $u_j^{(2)}$ are suitable distributions of finite order $k-j$ supported in $[-1,1]$. Are there any counterexamples to this?

Comment: If $u$ is supported on "$x$-axis union $y$-axis" then I expect $u$ to be a sum of "distribution supported on $x$-axis," "distribution supported on $y$-axis," and "distribution supported at origin." But so far it's just a feeling; I haven't tried to prove it.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. The restricted distribution $u|_{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}}$ will split as above, because it is supported on non-intersecting pieces of the axes.  Extending it (non-uniquely) to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and taking the difference shows that the difference must be a sum of derivatives of the unit measure at the origin. But such a sum is contained in either representation.